# table of content section numbering dots remove

Tags: table-of-contents, babel

I want to remove the dots from the section numbering from the ToC. Babel is enabled. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```latex
\def\magyarOptions{defaults=hu-min,sectiondot=none}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\def\magyarOptions{defaults=hu-min,sectiondot=none}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In your MWE you have

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```

In the `article` class sections in the ToC do not normally have dotted leaders but your `\cftsecleader` code makes them have dotted leaders. Delete at least the second line above.